# Django select filtered related object

Tags: python-3.x, django, join, orm

I have 3 models:

```py
class ForumTopic(models.Model):
    author          = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

class ForumMessage(models.Model):
    topic           = models.ForeignKey(ForumTopic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author          = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ForumMessageVote(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message         = models.ForeignKey(ForumMessage,   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote          = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to select all **ForumMessage** for specific **ForumTopic** and attach to result of this query **ForumMessageVote** filtered by specific **User** and current **ForumMessage**.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with subquery (I checked in the python console, and it works):

```py
vote=ForumMessageVote.objects.filter(message=OuterRef("pk")).filter(user=request.user)
messages=ForumMessage.objects.all().annotate(user_vote=Subquery(vote.values('vote')[:1]))
```

How to get the vote in view:

```py
v=messages.objects.get(author=request.user).user_vote
```

In the template:

```python
{% for msg in messages %}
{{msg.user_vote}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to filter `ForumMessageVote` objects

The information you require will be available via the results of the queryset

```
ForumMessageVote.objects.filter(
    user = the_selected_user, 
    message__topic = the_selected_topic 
).select_related(
    'message', 'message__topic' )
```

If you already know the ids of the user or the topic, for example via an URL, then you can filter `user_id=uid` or `message__topic_id=tid`

Comment: I want to iterate over all messages in template and get current user's vote for every message.

Comment: OK. Thanks, I try this.

Comment: Hmm...  But ForumMessageVote objects can be missing (if user never vote message)

Comment: Yes. I think that if you want to include objects that the user hasn't voted for, you will need more than one DB query. Like Hamid Rajabi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have used two different models for votes and message, you have make two dependent queries:

```
ForumMessages= ForumMessage.objects.filter(topic="specificTopic")
ForumMessageVotes=ForumMessageVote.object.filter(message__in=ForumMessages)
```

However, I can't see any reason not to use "vote" as an attribute of the "message" model; it will reduce redundancy.

Comment: I think to use this as fallback method and check vote is of this message when dispaly message in template's loop over all messages.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 